# Passing django variable in ajax data

Tags: ajax, django

I would like ajax to post some variables which have been created in a view.
My problem is that it isn't written in the proper way and anything is sent to my post request when I am looking at the chrome inspecter.

This is my javascript function :

```
function submitDataTable() {
            let table = $(document.getElementById('datatable')).DataTable()
            let advisedPriceColumn = table.column('advised_price:name')
            let advisedPriceData = advisedPriceColumn.data().toArray()

            $.ajaxSetup({
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' }
            })
            $.ajax({
            url: 'submit/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                advisedPrice: advisedPriceData,
                normal_price: '{{ normal_price|safe }}',
            },
            processData: false,
            success: res => {
                alert('Bien ouej mon vieux')
                location.reload()
            },
            error: xhr => {
                alert(xhr.responseText.split('\n')[1])
            }
            })
        };
```

These are some of the variables of my view that I would like to pass in my JS function:

```
return render(request,'livedb_model/typeDetail.html',{
        'property':property,
        'roomtype':roomtype,
        'invdf':invdf,
        'price_advised_list':price_advised_list,
        'price_list':price_list,
        'occupancy_list':occupancy_list,
        'c_occupancy_list':c_occupancy_list,
        'normal_price_list':normal_price_list[:100],
        'normal_price':normal_price,
        'week_day_multi':week_day_multi,
        'week_end_multi':week_end_multi,
        'max_discount':max_discount,
        'max_markup':max_markup,
        'coccCategory':coccCategory,
        'agressiveness':agressiveness
        })
```

And this is a screenshot of the chrome inspector, where we can see that only an [object Object] is passing
[image]

Please can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use django tags in .js file, what you can do is set data attributes in html like -

```
<input type="text" data="{{ normal_price|safe }}" id="id_normal_price" value="">
```

and then get it into your js like -

```
normal_price: $("#id_normal_price").attr("data")
```

you can set data values in any html tag.

Look at - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp